# Documents.Open using FileSystemObject returns "5174 - could not find the file" but not always

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to convert all docx files in a folder to PDF. 
To accomplish my goals I put all the files (only docx) in the same folder than the docm and run the macro. It worked, but now it doesn't, even with the same files doesn't work anymore. Sometimes works for the first file and stop working with the following alert:
"Runtime error '5174':
This file could not be found
(C:\Users...\Archive.docx)"

The problem is always on the Documents.Open

Tried "OpenAndRepair",  "ReadOnly", Putting nothing, etc.

```
Sub Converter()
    Dim CurrentFolder As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim myPath As String

    'Store Information About Word File
    myPath = ActiveDocument.FullName

    FileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1)
    Dim strCaminho As String

    strCaminho = ActiveDocument.Path

    Dim fso As Object 'Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As Object 'Scripting.Folder
    Dim fl As Object 'Scripting.File
    Dim atual As String


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strCaminho)


        For Each fl In fld.Files

        If fl.Name <> FileName Then 'doesn't try to open the file with macro
        Documents.Open FileName:=fl.Name

        Word_ExportPDF 'A function that works

        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        End If


        Next fl

End Sub
```

My code is a Frankenstein from other macros, is there a better way to Automatize this conversion?

Comment: You don't need to parse out the `FileName ` - `Word.Document` give you direct access to that with `.Name`. The first thing I would do is collect the names of the documents first, *then* export them.  You're modifying the directory contents as you iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement what Comintern had proposed:

> You don't need to parse out the FileName - Word.Document give you direct access to that with .Name. The first thing I would do is collect the names of the documents first, then export them. You're modifying the directory contents as you iterate over it. - Comintern

Then, the following can be added to the code to check for valid document extensions:

```
If fl.Name <> FileName Then 'doesn't try to open the file with macro

    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fl.Path)) = "docx" Then  '<----This Line
        Documents.Open FileName:=fl.Path   '<--------------------This Line

        Word_ExportPDF 'A function that works

        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    End if

End if
```